# How does a subpass dependency guarantee the layout transition of a swapchain image happens after presentation engine finish reading the very image?

Tags: vulkan

I'm going through vulkan-tutorial:

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Rendering_and_presentation

And I found something weired:
[image]

How does this subpass dependency guarantee the layout transition(from UNDEFINED to COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL)of swapchain image happens after present engine finish reading(or working on) this swapchain image?i.e.Layout transition of this swapchain image bewteen external and subpass0 guarantees to happen after the imageAvailableSemaphores is signaled.

I did find some explanations on this topics from this blog:

http://themaister.net/blog/2019/08/14/yet-another-blog-explaining-vulkan-synchronization/

> External subpass dependencies Render passes in Vulkan have a concept
> of EXTERNAL subpass dependencies. This is arguably the most
> misunderstood aspect of Vulkan sync. I’d like to dedicate a section to
> this, because too many developers are lured into using it in cases
> where it’s not terribly useful and very likely to cause bugs.
>
> The main purpose of external subpass dependencies is to deal with
> initialLayout and finalLayout of an attachment reference. If
> initialLayout != layout used in the first subpass, the render pass is
> forced to perform a layout transition.
>
> If you don’t specify anything else, that layout transition will wait
> for nothing before it performs the transition. **Or rather, the driver
> will inject a dummy subpass dependency for you with srcStageMask =
> TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT. This is not what you want since it’s almost certainly
> going to be a race condition.** You can set up a subpass dependency with
> the appropriate srcStageMask and srcAcessMask. The external subpass
> dependency is basically just a vkCmdPipelineBarrier injected for you
> by the driver. The whole premise here is that it’s theoretically
> better to do it this way because the driver has more information, but
> this is questionable, at least on current hardware and drivers.
>
> There is a very similar external subpass dependency setup for
> finalLayout. If finalLayout differs from the last use in a subpass,
> driver will transition into the final layout automatically. Here you
> get to change dstStageMask/dstAccessMask. If you do nothing here, you
> get BOTTOM_OF_PIPE/0, which can actually be just fine. A prime use
> case here is swapchain images which have finalLayout =
> PRESENT_SRC_KHR.
>
> Essentially, you can ignore external subpass dependencies. Their added
> complexity give very little gain. Render pass compatibility rules also
> imply that if you change even minor things like which stages to wait
> for, you need to create new pipelines! This is dumb, and will
> hopefully be fixed at some point in the spec.
>
> However, while the usefulness of external subpass dependencies is
> questionable, they have some convenient use cases I’d like to go over:

> Automatically transitioning swapchain images Typically, swapchain
> images are always just used once per frame, and we can deal with all
> synchronization using external subpass dependencies. We want
> initialLayout = UNDEFINED, and finalLayout = PRESENT_SRC_KHR.
>
> **srcStageMask is COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT which lets us link up with the
> swapchain acquire semaphore.** For this case, we will need an external
> subpass dependency. For the finalLayout transition after the render
> pass, we are fine with BOTTOM_OF_PIPE being used. We’re going to use
> semaphores here anyways.
>
> I also do this in Granite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of struggling with spec,I found this stackoverflow post that perfectly solved my question:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339191/synchronizing-a-render-pass-layout-transition-with-a-semaphore-in-acquire-pres